# Can I use Hamcrest's Matchers.containsInRelativeOrder?

Tags: java, hamcrest

I'm a little confused. I see function `containsInRelativeOrder` in [the code](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/Matchers.java#L1021):

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <E> org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends E>> containsInRelativeOrder(E... items) {
    return org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInRelativeOrder.containsInRelativeOrder(items);
}
```

but I'm getting a method-not-found error when I try to use that method (with Hamcrest 1.3) and I don't see it in [the javadoc](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html).

Is this a version issue? Is the method not present in 1.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Corrected** thanks to @Tom.

Yes, it is a version issue!  [1.3](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/commit/36d525e1e425006939a77aec5183aecd7c775b05) is from 2012.  The function was added in Dec. 2014 by [commit 99bc9421a719782c6357f991c891af48d6e9de4a](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/commit/99bc9421a719782c6357f991c891af48d6e9de4a).

The first version of this function was added in Nov. 2014 by [commit 5ed2d06688f9d3b445b98b13056223b79318a614](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/commit/5ed2d06688f9d3b445b98b13056223b79318a614).  At that time, it lived in a separate file, [`collection/IsIterableContainingInRelativeOrder.java`](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/5ed2d06688f9d3b445b98b13056223b79318a614/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInRelativeOrder.java).

Comment: Have you checked *when* version 1.3 was released? Might solve that question for you.

Comment: You're welcome. There are several new features which can't be used, because the latest release is so damn old. Quite sad, but I still like Hamcrest :D

Comment: Thanks! I thought this was the case, but I was really hoping somebody would prove me wrong.

Comment: Sidenote - you can use it by copying [the matcher](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInRelativeOrder.java) into your own code, if you don't want to fight with compiling your own full copy of Hamcrest. It's BSD license, so this doesn't introduce any new requirements beyond what's required when you import the Hamcrest library. [License](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/LICENSE.txt)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be available in version 1.3 ([see the Javadoc of version 1.3](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/))